# Unable to create scratch org successfully in Visual Studio Code

Tags: lightning-web-components, salesforcedx, vs-code, sfdx-plugin

I have authorized dev hub org successfully and now trying to create default scratch org using visual studio code but getting following error:

```
sfdx force:org:create -f config\project-scratch-def.json --setalias LightningWebComponent --setdefaultusername
```

> ERROR running force:org:create:  Successfully created org with ID:
>   00DN0000000CgnWMAS and name: test-uuplqwe9abid@example.com. However,
>   the My Domain URL
>   https://innovation-ability-7287-dev-ed.cs6.my.salesforce.com/ has not
>   finished propagating.
>
> Some commands may not work as expected until the
>   My Domain DNS propagation is complete.
>
> sfdx force:org:create -f
>   config\project-scratch-def.json --setalias LightningWebComponent
>   --setdefaultusername ended with exit code 1

Comment: What does your Scratch Org Definition File look like?

Comment: @KrisGoncalves Where can I find definition file?

Comment: `config --> project-scratch-def.json`

Answer (score 3):

This is not really an error. You just need to wait a few more minutes for the Domain Name to be propagated.

Just try to open the org with `sfdx force:org:open` later, and it will work.

If you want the command to exit with a non error exit code, you can just increase the timeout using the `--wait` flag, so that the DNS has the time to propagate:

```
sfdx force:org:create -f config\project-scratch-def.json --setalias LightningWebComponent --setdefaultusername --wait 30
```

Most likely, if you just retry to create a scratch org as is it will just work.

Comment: tailon the response from the sfdx command run says Error  but as you are saying this is not an error I am confused. In the event if devhub does not have mydomain enabled would it not be erroring - but as per my understanding If you don’t enable and deploy My Domain, you can’t link your namespace to the Dev Hub org. Are you hinting the error is misnomer in this scenario and the scratchorg did create

Comment: The error is about the scratch org domain, not dev hub one. The error is more something like « the scratch org is not ready yet, wait a few more minutes ». If you try to open the scratch org it will work.

Comment: @FabienTaillon Tried as you described. Ran sfdx force:org:open command after some time. Now, it throwing following error:
ERROR running force:org:open:  No AuthInfo found for name LightningWebComponent

Comment: @FabienTaillon tried one more command as well:

Starting SFDX: Open Default Scratch Org

sfdx force:org:open
ERROR running force:org:open:  No AuthInfo found for name LightningWebComponent
sfdx force:org:open ended with exit code 1

Comment: Can you try recreating the scratch org with an increased wait flag ? Like --wait 60 ?

Comment: @FabienTaillon Here is the output:

PS D:\Salesforce-Development\LWC> sfdx force:org:create -f config\project-scratch-def.json --setalias LightningWebComponent1 --setdefaultusername --wait 60

ERROR running force:org:create:  Successfully created org with ID: 00D1y0000008bTOEAY and name: test-tof38xqpjftf@example.com. However, the My Domain URL https://ability-page-3086-dev-ed.cs114.my.salesforce.com/ has not finished propagating. Some commands may not work as expected until the My Domain DNS propagation is complete.